# Can I use my own custom animated gifs as markers on Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use different animated cartoon images (gifs) as markers on Google Maps; can I do this with the API?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ehoxoq/151/edit)):

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(59.219521,15.1419873);
var marker;
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: position
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: position,
        icon: "http://heera.it/wp-content/themes/heerait/img/blog/me.png"
    });
}
```

You just need to use `icon:icon-url` when creating the marker.

**Update:**

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map:map,
  draggable:false,
  optimized:false, // <-- required for animated gif
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: position,
  icon: "http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-01-35/e8nZC.gif"
});
```

[Example Here.](http://jsbin.com/ehoxoq/153/edit)

Comment: Ok, great!  I see you used a *.png in your example but I could also use an animated *.gif?

Comment: I just tried adding the following *.gif based on the example you did above but the *.gif doesn't show any movement. :(

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-01-35/e8nZC.gif

Comment: I figured it out; I had to add optimized: false, to it.

Comment: I've updated the answer for future reference, thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: The post require animation not a png. The gif doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you can do this:

```
function showMarkerFeature(p) {
var oF = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: p,
    //set the image src path here
    icon: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png" 
});
identifyMarker.setVisible(false);
map.setCenter(p);

return oF;
}
```